# window.onsubmit not being executed

Tags: javascript

Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onsubmit = function {
    alert('onsubmit');}
</script>
```

I can't see any popup whenever the page is submitted.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In future JS trouble/questions, focus on client side source code, not on server side source code. I.e. just do rightclick and View Source in webbrowser and base off your question and JS code on that. JS users do not necessarily know about any existing server side languages/frameworks which autogenerates HTML/JS code. If necessary, copy/simplify the generated HTML output into a plain vanilla `.html` file. In case you get the answer then it's just a matter of rewriting server side code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML/JS output.

Answer (score 0):

The window doesn't have an .onsubmit event - you need to add the function to the form element.

Comment: That is pretty strange since I had the same code on a page defined without ui tags where the script was declared within the <head> tag and did work. The popup did come out. Thanks